# Connecting a List Form to a form that produces the tables

Tags: c#, forms

The customer welcome page ask for the customer ID from accounts 

 I want to connect 2 forms, 1 that when you click the go button, the form will go to form #2 and display the list into tables.

Form 1: takes in Cid from the  Accounts table: http://puu.sh/hnp4G/eeb8da0a87.png

```
   public partial class WelcomeCust : Form 
        {

            OleDbConnection db = new OleDbConnection();
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            public WelcomeCust()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                db.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\\ChattBankMDB.mdb";
            }

            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                //Code for looking up the 

                using (OleDbCommand da = new OleDbCommand("select Cid From Accounts", db))
                {
                    db.Open();
                    DataTable schema = db.GetSchema("Tables");
                    List<Accounts> TableNames = new List<Accounts>();
                    foreach (DataRow row in schema.Rows)
                    {
                        TableNames.Add(row[0].ToString());
                    }
    da.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cid", textBox1.Text);
                    da.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    return TableNames;
                    db.Close();
                }
            }
```

Form 2: Display the table of your accounts:http://puu.sh/hnpgr/e1d31930cf.png

```
public partial class CustomerAccounts : Form
    {
        public CustomerAccounts()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void tableLayoutPanel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

`TableNames.Add(row[0].ToString());` and `return TableNames();` give me errors as well.:

```
Error   2   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'ChattBank.Accounts'    

Error   3   Since 'ChattBank.WelcomeCust.button1_Click(object, System.EventArgs)' returns void, a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression
```

Answer (score 0):

the error is quite selfexplanatory, your list expecting an object `Accounts`, but you passed a string, and since this method's return value is void, you shouldn't have return statement. If you need access `TableNames` in other methods, try define it as a private field of your `WelcomeCust` class